# how to Get the value of input type hidden in modal using ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Good day.. 
i have modal and inside the modal i have div class

```
<div id="user-details-content" class="modal-body">
   ...
</div>
```

i supply the content inside that modal using ajax. 
this is the supplied content:

```
<div id="hidden" class="hidden">
   <input type="hidden" name="id" class="id" id="id" value="1">
   <input type="hidden" value="email@email.com" class="email">
</div>
```

Now i try to get that input type="hidden" using this ajax

```
var id = $(this).parents('#user-details-content').find('.id').val();
```

but it returns undefined in my console.log

any suggestions ? on how to get that input type="hidden" and the value ?

EDIT - This is my ajax function

```
function inquiryId(){
    var id = $(this).parents('#user-details-content').find('.id').val();
    console.log(id);
    $.ajax({
        url: 'php_file.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: { id: id,
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(result){
            console.log(result);
        }

    });
}
```

Comment: Is `var id = $(this).parents('#user-details-content').find('.id').val();` called within `$.ajax()` success handler ?, or following `$.ajax()` call ? Can include `$.ajax()` `js` at Question ?

Comment: What is the context of your `this`? What is the output of `console.log( this )`? When using an ID selector -- IDs by definition are unique -- you do not need to use `$(this).parents('....')` or any such methods. Have you tried `var id = $('#user-details-content').find('.id').val()`?

Comment: `function inquiryId(){
  var id = $(this).parents('#user-details-content').find('.inq_id').val();
  console.log(id);
  $.ajax({
   url: 'php_file.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: { id: id,
   },
            dataType: 'json',
   success: function(result){
    console.log(result);
   }
   
  });
 }`

This is my ajax for calling the input type

Comment: `id` at `var id = $(this).parents('#user-details-content').find('.inq_id').val();` appear to have different `id` than at Question ? `inquiryId` called before `$.ajax()` appends element to document ?

Comment: Yes PeterKA i tried `var id = $('#user-details-content').find('.id').val()` but in my google chrome console it returns undifined

Comment: _"i supply the content inside that modal using ajax."_ Where is content appended to modal ?

Comment: guest271314 - this is the content
`<div id="hidden" class="hidden">
   <input type="hidden" name="id" class="id" id="id" value="1">
   <input type="hidden" value="email@email.com" class="email">
</div>`

Comment: post the html that gets loaded by the dom.

Comment: `$(this)` in the `function` you are calling will not have reference to any control and obviously the `val` will be undefined... Try to provide full details on how you are trying to fetch, where you are calling this function etc..

Comment: guest271314 -  the jquery library is loaded successfully.. now i only test the `var id = $(this).parents('#user-details-content').find('input:[type="hidden" name="id"]').val();`  it in my google chrome developer tools and in my console log it returns undefined

Comment: @Jayson Yes, though where is content actually appended to modal , or document at `js` at Question ? Is `var id = $(this).parents('#user-details-content').find('.id').val();` called before content is appended to modal or document ?

Comment: @guest271314  i append the content inside this modal body `<div id="user-details-content" class="modal-body">
   ...
</div>`

Comment: Where in `js` at Question text is `<div id="user-details-content" class="modal-body"> ... </div>` appended to modal or document ?

Comment: @guest271314 it appends in my modal..

Comment: @Jayson_"it appends in my modal.."_ How ? Can include text of `js` that appends `html` to modal ?

Answer (score 0):

the problem may occurs because you loaded the html after the DOM loaded.
i guess you have kind of event listener right ?

A workaround could be doing something like :

```
$(document).on('some_event', '#your_css_selector', function(e){
    // do your stuff here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just want to get the input type=hidden value?

JQuery can get the value no matter it's hidden or show.

```js
$('#id').val();
$('.email').val();
```

this is ok.

Comment: I have insert the post,  you can not see that ? `$('#id').val(); $('.email').val();` this.

Answer (score 0):

From the line of code:

```
var id = $(this).parents('#user-details-content').find('.id').val();
```

If you know the exact **`id`** and the **`class`** attributes of the **`input[type="hidden"]`**, may I suggest using **`$("#id").val()`** and **`$(".email").val()`**. Below is a snippet to demonstrate my suggestion, hope it helps.

```js
$(function(){
  $("button").click(function(event) {
    buttonSubmit_OnClick();
  });
});


function buttonSubmit_OnClick() {
  var message;
  message = "Hello " + $("#id").val() + "! ";
  message += $(".email").val();
  
  $("p").html($("p").html() + "<br>" + message);

  /* $.ajax() code-block goes here */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="hidden" class="hidden">
  <input type="hidden" name="id" class="id" id="id" value="1">
  <input type="hidden" value="email@email.com" class="email">
  <button>Click me!</button><!-- this is for demo! -->
</div>
<p></p><!-- this is for demo! -->
```

**As a side note**:

For better client-side code optimization:

1. **`$(this)`** is *powerful*, but also a *wild-card*. jQuery is always updating the `this`, so, `this` may not always be what you expect it to be. Best be used only when you really have to, when you do, store its reference in a variable. Remember, with *great power, comes great responsibility*.
2. **ID-Based Selectors** are much faster because they handled by using **`document.getElementById()`** which is native to the browser instead of going through jQuery's sizzle selection engine.
3. **Being specific** if possible. Avoid universal selectors such as `.children()` or `.parents()`.

Here is a more eloquent read on [optimizing jQuery selectors](https://learn.jquery.com/performance/optimize-selectors/).